# Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.Subject.isUpdateable() is false in force.com site

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, security

We have managed a package where we are using `apexrest` through force.com site to update the task records. This works fine unless we add security enforce through apex getDescribe() like,

```
Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.Subject.isUpdateable()
```

Getting `false` value for above in the site context even when we have enabled:

> Access Activities on Site Profile
>
> Field level security for Subject field on Site Profile

There are several fields like this including custom fields.
Is something missing here?
If not is there any workaround for it?